# Display mediaelement.js audio player inline

Tags: html, css, mediaelement.js

How do I display the `MediaElement.js` audio player inline? (surrounded by text).

I've unsuccessfully tried editing the CSS [here on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbjapan/3fog266s/1/) to:

**CSS**

```
.mejs-container{
    position: relative; /*I tried changing this */
    clear: none; /* and added this */
}
.mejs-clear {
    clear:both;  /* tried "none" */
}
```

**HTML**

```
I want the player ON the same line with the second line of text<br/>
This Line, here -> <audio id="mejs-player" src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/AirReview-Landmarks-02-ChasingCorporate.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio> <br/>
Not This Line.
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#mejs-player').mediaelementplayer({
    // API options
    features: ['playpause','progress','duration','tracks'],
    audioWidth: 200,
    alwaysShowControls: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a line to .mejs-container's css should do it

```
display:inline-block;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/3fog266s/2/